# python String to number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert a string that contains a decimal number like this.

```
bet1size = "0.00000001"
```

I've tried

betsize = int(bet1size)

but that comes up with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.00000001'
```

I've also tried

```
betsize = float(bet1size)
```

but this comes up with 1e-08
and

```
betsize = Decimal(bet1size)
```

comes with with 1E-8

Why does it this happen and how can I do it properly?

Comment: what do you want as output? 0.00000001 is the same as 1e-08 aka 10^-8

Comment: I want to convert it to a number so I can double it then I was going to convert it back to a string, but like this the string ends up being 2e-08 not 0.00000002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scientific notation is just a convenient way of storing/printing a floating point number. When there are a lot of leading zeros as in your example, the scientific notation might be easier to read.

In order to print a specific number of digits after a decimal point, you can specify a format string with print:

```
format(float(bet1size), '.8f')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's being done "properly" by `float()`. `1e-08` *is* "0.00000001".

It's just a matter of how you format it for printing, the number is the same.

Answer (score 0):

`int` means **integer**. You can't store a **decimal** number in a **int**.
For the two other, it means 1 * 10^-8, which equals to 0.00000001.